# How to show the Percent Completion of each division in each course?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a web-based application that tracks the training

for each employee in the company. I have the following database

design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, DivisionCode
Division Table: SapCode, DivisionName
Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
Group Table: GroupID, GroupName
Employee_Course Table: Username, CourseID
```

(The first attribute in each table is the primary key except for the last table)

I have **to implement a chart or table that shows the percent completion of each division in each course of these courses**, but I don't know how to come up with this query. The query should show the DivisionName, CourseName, the Number of Participants in each Course and the Percent Completion

**So could you please help me with this query?**

Comment: What indicates completion of a course?

Comment: Percent Completion means the total number of participants or employees who took the course / the total number of employees in that division. the Employee_Course Table: shows the username of the employees with the ID of the taken or completed courses

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.DivisionName, a.CourseName, a.ParticipantsCount, ParticipantCount / EmployeeCount * 100 as PercentCompleted
from (
    select DivisionName, count(*) as EmployeeCount
    from Division d
    inner join Employee e on d.DivisionCode  = e.DivisionCode 
    group by DivisionName
) dc
inner join (
    select d.DivisionName, c.CourseName, count(*) as ParticipantCount
    from Course c
    inner join Employee_Course ec on c.CourseID = ec.CourseID
    inner join Employee e on ec.Username = e.Username
    inner join Division d on e.DivisionCode  = d.DivisionCode 
    group by DivisionName, CourseName
) a on dc.DivisionName = a.DivisionName
```

Comment: Thank you dude for you help. I tried to execute your query in the SQLServer Management Studio but I got the following errors and I don't know why: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: He's done inner outer join, probably a typo, should be inner join I think

Comment: @MohammedAli typo, fixed above